# Add Meta Title, Meta Keyword and Meta Description In Custom Module

Tags: magento

I'm new in magento. I just want to know how can I Add Meta Title, Meta Keyword and Meta Description in Custom Module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to set meta information:

1. Please Insert this code in custom module layout.xml file.

```
<reference name = "head">
   <action method = "setTitle"><title>Accessory</title></action>
   <action method = "setKeywords"><title>module, keywords</title></action>
   <action method = "setDescription"><title>Module Description</title></action>
</reference>
```

2. Please open your module block file from below mention location and set Meta Title/Keyword/Description

app/code/local/namespace/yourmodule/block/yourmodule.php

```
public function _prepareLayout() {        
    $head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    $head->setTitle("Your Title");
    $head->setKeywords("your, keywords, anything");
    $head->setDescription("Your Description");
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Comment: do you need to change both files? xml and block